# PHP JavaScript - Store value from first drop down list when using $_SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I have a PHP code and I have a dropdown list of a list of countries in a SQL database. The values are sorted:

`Continent (Row 1) - > Country (Row 2) -> City (Row 3)`

Eg.

```
Europe -> England -> London
Europe -> England -> London
Europe -> Gemany -> Munich
North America -> New York -> Manhattan
North America -> California -> Los Angeles
```

This is my code for when I choose the first continent

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tableName = 'categories';

ob_start();
session_start(); 

//Get values from table
$sqlPrimaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName GROUP BY primary_category");
$sqlPrimaryCategory->execute();
echo '<form id="primary_category" name="primary_category" action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="primary_category" onChange="this.form.submit()" size = "4"> ';
while ($result = $sqlPrimaryCategory->fetch()) {
    echo '<option value="';
    echo $result['primary_category'];
    echo '">';
    echo $result['primary_category'];
    echo '</option>'; 
}
echo '</select>'; 
echo '</form>'; 
echo '<p><strong>You have selected</strong> <em>'.$_POST['primary_category'].'</em></p>';
$_SESSION['primary_category'] = $_POST['primary_category'];

echo 'Your selection is ' . $_SESSION['primary_category'];
$primaryCategory = $_SESSION['primary_category'];
```

then based on the first value I get to choose the second value e.g. if I choose Europe - I will have a choice between choosing England or Germany.

This is done using my second code to get the second value

```
//Get values from table
$sqlSecondaryCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE primary_category = :primary_category GROUP BY secondary_category");
$sqlSecondaryCategory->execute(array(':primary_category'=>$primaryCategory));
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="secondary_category" onChange="this.form.submit()" size = "4"> ';
while ($result = $sqlSecondaryCategory->fetch()) {
    echo '<option value="';
    echo $result['secondary_category'];
    echo '">';
    echo $result['secondary_category'];
    echo '</option>'; 
}
echo '</select>'; 
echo '</form>'; 
echo '<p><strong>You have selected</strong> <em>'.$_POST['secondary_category'].'</em></p>';
$_SESSION['secondary_category'] = $_POST['secondary_category'];

echo 'Your selection is ' . $_SESSION['secondary_category'];
$secondaryCategory = $_SESSION['secondary_category'];
```

Unfortunately, when I choose in the second category i.e. the country the value from `$_SESSION['primary_category']` and only `$_SESSION['secondary_country']` is being displayed.

I would like that when I choose say Europe, the `$_SESSION['primary_category']` is kept.

My suspecsion is that since they both HTML forms contain `onChange="this.form.submit()"` each, one is deleting the other.

I guess if I change `onChange="this.form.submit()"` and is submitted on the basis of the form name or id, I wouldn't have this problem. Unfortuantely I am not familiar with JavaScript

Comment: start using error_reporting(E_ALL) for your dev! maybe if(!empty($_POST['primary_category'])){$_SESSION['primary_category'] = $_POST['primary_category'];}

also you should fix "FROM $tableName", at least it messes up performance/caches..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $_SESSION use setcookie() so both PHP and JavaScript can use the variables you set for those selections. This will be much easier than what you are trying to accomplish.

PHP:
$_COOKIE as the getter and setcookie() as a setter.

JavaScript
document.cookie reads all the set cookies and you can explode them into an array to find your specific cookie.

Hope that helps